# How to retrieve a UI Schedule Job metadata from Org?

Tags: scheduled-apex, vs-code, scheduled-job

I know that we can use code to schedule jobs, but I already have a UI based Schedule Job on my org, and I only want to fetch the metadata for that.

I have org browser in my VS Code, but I can't find the metadata in any of the folder, upon searching over internet, I still have not found any solution.

Can we at all package Schedule Jobs created through UI, or writing code is the only option?